# Python Regex: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Match'

Tags: python, regex

This is the first time I'm using regular expressions with python and I'm trying to figure out why it thinks the error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Match'"

I'm doing this in Jupyter notebook. What am I doing wrong here? I see only one other unhelpful question out there with this same missing attribute error.

```
import re
grp =  "Application: Company Name / 184010 - Application Development / 184010 - Contract Express"
rgx = "\w+ *(?!.*-)"
res = grp.match(rgx)
print(res)
```

Comment: [Wrong syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile). Either `re.match(rgx, grp)` or `re.compile(rgx).match(grp)`.

Comment: What are you trying to match here?

Comment: All words after the final dash @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @meowgoesthedog thanks!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisenweirdly I'm not getting a match, the result is none yet in the regex tester I used it matches fine.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) but that starts at the beginning of the string. You could use [findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) instead:

```
import re
grp =  "Application: Company Name / 184010 - Application Development / 184010 - Contract Express"
rgx = "\w+ *(?!.*-)"
res = re.findall(rgx, grp)
print(res)  # ['Contract ', 'Express']
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/Sf1Q4V)

If there should also not be a forward slash following, you could add that to a character class together with the hyphen.

Note that to not match the space after the word you could omit the space followed by the asterix `*` from the pattern.

```
\w+(?!.*[-/])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VxE2JM/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/JVb3SI)